# xamarin.forms mscorlib конфликт зависимости

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Собрал проект, всё хорошо. Запускаю андроид приложение и выводится такая ошибка

> App4.Android ->
>   C:\Users\admin\source\repos\App4\App4\App4.Android\bin\Debug\App4.Android.dll
>   2>  не удается разрешить конфликт между "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" и "mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e".
>   Произвольный выбор "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
>   ========== Перестроение всех проектов: успешно: 2, с ошибками: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========

Это новый проект, сгенереный visual studio. Уже весь гугл прошерстил, ничего не помогало. Очевидно что конфликт между версиями microlib, но не могу найти где сменить версию, чтобы всё начало работать. Попытался изменить ссылку, но не вышло. Он просто не даёт сменить ссылку. Может кто-то сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Если нашел решение этой проблемы напиши пожалуйста, возникла аналогичная проблема

Comment: Решения до сих пор не нашёл

Answer (score 0):

Теплый прием в духе Xamarin.Forms:

Создаем проект по шаблону VS...
Редактор кода: код красный. У VS агония, новичек посмел установить нагрузку Xamarin для VS.

Сначала у меня был конфликт зависимостей nuget. Потом он как-то исчез уж не знаю как. В руководстве по исправлению ошибок от Miscorosft(так правильней) сказано, что надо установить AppCompat, который включает обе нужные мне зависимости. Не помню сделал ли я это, но ошибки исчезли.

Пытался сбилидть проект. Чем кончилось не помню. Но ничем хорошим это точно. Его надо же где-то развернуть для тестов... У моего телефона adb криво работает (вероятно, из-за рутирования и кастомной прошивки), поэтому отлаживать через него нельзя. Попробовал через другой аппарат с версией android 8 (причем, сам проект таргетился вроде на 5 версию) - работает.
А также делал "Архивацию" (пункт по пкм проекта андроид) с подписыванием в Release-конфигурации - и этот апк нормально установился на моем телефоне (android 5.0 и работало приложение).

Натыкаемся на эмулятор VS'os Emulator. Подозрительный он какой-то. Пытаемся [заюзать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/999981/visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE) его. Хорошо. Заюзали. Попробуем установить CatLog-приложение на некоторый жмулируемый девайс с android 5.0(чисто для примера) с 4pda для тестов на жизнеспособность - работает. Кстати, ни один эмулятор выше android 5.0/1 не запустился. Причины неизвестны, но закономерность прослеживается.
Так что тут у нас еще? Конфликт mscorlib Version=4.0.0.0 и Version=2.0.5.0, да пустяк, пусть игнорирует.

Запустим наконец отладку. Хорошо, приложение упало. Без следа. Пробуем найти логи... Поиски... На следующий день - о, в vs оказывается есть таб для логов logcat. Что тут у нас:

*Got a SIGILL while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.*

Ну ерунда какая-то, нашли из-за чего приложение закрывать. Смотрим еще:

```
07-07 21:46:10.346 D/Mono    ( 1920): Image addref mscorlib[0xaff0c100] (asmctx DEFAULT) -> mscorlib.dll[0xafb8b400]: 2

07-07 21:46:10.346 D/Mono    ( 1920): Prepared to set up assembly 'mscorlib' (mscorlib.dll)

07-07 21:46:10.347 D/Mono    ( 1920): AOT: image 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "mscorlib.dll.so" not found

07-07 21:46:10.347 D/Mono    ( 1920): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d16-1/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d16-1/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/mscorlib.dll.so" not found

07-07 21:46:10.347 D/Mono    ( 1920): Config attempting to parse: 'mscorlib.dll.config'.
```

Начинаем гуглоинг. Я нашел эти ссылки:

1. https://qa-help.ru/questions/konflikt-versii-mscorlib-vo-vremya-sborki
2. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101704/mscorlib-conflict-between-versions
3. http://www.ohandroid.com/xamarin-forms-android-app-crashes-x.html
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746267/error-image-en-fsharp-core-resources-dll-so-not-found-dlopen-failed-condi
5. http://www.cyberforum.ru/xamarin/thread1868910.html
6. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362219/xamarin-android-aot-module-mscorlib-dll-so-not-found
7. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/79075/aot-module-mscorlib-dll-so-not-found-dlopen-failed

Предложения не работают или ответов нет. Или я не углядел чего-то. Ни конфигурирование процессора для Hyper-V, ни отключение общего рантайма (это все вроде предложения из одной ссылки) не помогло. Хотя, кое-где говорилось, что такого бага не наблюдалось в v7. Я так понимаю это MonoAndroid v7. А вот в v8, v9 как был этот баг, так и остался.

Comment: Первая ссылка в списке - это автоперевод ответа на StackOverflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881648/mscorlib-version-conflict-during-build, просто в нем нет ссылки на оригинал (хоть ее и требует лицензия SO)