# Visual Studio’s Emulator for Android что с ним стало?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

Описание эмулятора [здесь](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/msft-android-emulator/). Но это какая-то волшебная страница. Начнем с того, что картинки, где должно быть видно, как запустить эмулятор из VS (то есть как он интегрирован в VS) битые: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на "[документацию](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/introducing-visual-studios-emulator-for-android/)". Какая-то небольшая обзорная заметка?
Есть [видео](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2014/516), где показано, как запускается VS эмулятор из VS... Но что-то я не вижу этих пунктов у себя в VS 2019 16.1.5.

О эмуляторе, который предлагает VS (google emulator):
Во всех руководствах по запуску эмулятора (вышел на них, когда читал как включить hyper-v) в VS фигурирует тормознутый qemu от гугла. У меня он, кстати, запускается как черное окно и жрет ~25% почти час. Так еще и менеджер avd в VS какой-то супер-тормозной. Где-то реально полчаса жрет диск на 100% и показывает анимацию загрузки. В диспетчере в разделе "подробно" написано, что основная часть потребления диска - колонка "прочих байт при вводе-выводе" - около 100 мб(проверял после загрузки).

Итак, мои вопросы:

1. Жив ли еще этот эмулятор и его команда разработки?
2. Как его интегрировать в VS, чтобы я мог вести отладку? Хотелось бы, конечно, пунктов в GUI VS для запуска эмулятора и обещанной супер-удобной отладки. Но если кто-то подскажет как подключить эмулируемый аппарат по adb, то тоже сойдет. Вроде как-то по сети можно?
3. Профили устройств у этого эмулятора нередактируемые. Но зачем мне девайс с 2гб ram, когда там будет запущено всего лишь одно приложение... Можно ли как-то править конфиги? Может в hyper-v часть настроек...

Comment: Вопрос к автору.
Так получилось запустить Visual Studio Emulator на Android Studio? Если да, то как?

Comment: Эмулятор запускаешь отдельно от Android Studio, а потом в Android Studio остается лишь подключиться к нему по adb. (как это сделать я уже написал, но для VS (аналогично для android studio))

Answer (score 1):

**ОТВЕТ НА ПУНКТ 3:**

Да, в "Диспетчер Hyper-V" (так можно и вводить для поиска) есть все параметры виртуальной машины (озу, кол-во вирт процессоров и тп):
[image: hyper-v]

Но по всей видимости эти параметры переопределяются при запуске эмулятора, поэтому посмотрите где расположены файлы вирт. машин:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каталогом выше можно найти cfg файлы, согласно которым оболочка управления эмуляторами запускает их:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Возможный вариант решения для пункта 2:**

Включаем в эмулируемом устройстве отладку по usb. Смотрим в "О системе" или как-то так "Общая информация" IP-адрес. У себя в cmd вводим adb connect ip:5555. После этого в VS появится пунктик для запуска с эмулятора. Надо еще не забыть добавить компиляцию в x86 для android-проекта, иначе будет ошибка развертывания. Получилось установить пару apk через adb. Однако, отладка так и не свершилась, т.к. приложение падало на старте (приложение чистое из шаблона VS сделано). Однако, сторонние apk с x86 запускаются нормально. В VS есть таб с фильтрованным Logcat из эмулятора.